# Can you tell how a macro got invoked in Rust?

Tags: syntax, macros, rust

Rust's macro support three forms of call syntax

```
macro! {...} 

macro! (...)

macro! [...]
```

Can tell which syntax was used to call the macro, from within the macro?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Since I have to enter at least 30 characters: *really* no.  There are no hacks, workarounds, or One Weird Tricks to get around this.  It just isn't possible. No one has implemented any way to do it, there's nothing planned, nothing proposed. It's not that it's forbidden or can't be implemented, it just hasn't been.

Comment: can you at least explain why it's not possible. Just saying no is a bit insufficient.

Comment: @mattgathu There's nothing to explain.  It just isn't possible.  No one has implemented any way to do it, there's nothing planned, nothing proposed.  It's not that it's forbidden or can't be implemented, it just hasn't been.